# Text document going From DOS to Linux in Vim

Tags: linux, vim

I was given a trace file in XML format (created on a Windows machine). When I open it in Vim or cat it on the command line (on Mac or Linux), it visually appears fine. But after an XML parser failed to load the document as I'd expect, I found out, after digging a little deeper, that there are non-printable chars througout:

```
h001:logs bill$ xxd trace.xml | head -n 3
0000000: fffe 3c00 3f00 7800 6d00 6c00 2000 7600  ..<.?.x.m.l. .v.
0000010: 6500 7200 7300 6900 6f00 6e00 3d00 2200  e.r.s.i.o.n.=.".
0000020: 3100 2e00 3000 2200 2000 6500 6e00 6300  1...0.". .e.n.c.
```

I then tried the following with no luck removing these non-printed chars:

```
:%s/[^[:print:]]//g
:%s/[^[:control:]]//g
:%s/[^[:null:]]//g
```

I'm figuring this is due to the fact I'm switching from Windows to Linux, but I'm not seeing any of the usual artifacts (e.g. ^M, ^@, etc).

Any thoughts on what's happening here and what would be the right way to remove these from within Vim?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to open a file with a 2-byte encoding like UTF-16 with an xaml-parser that expects ANSI or UTF-8.

Comment: This isn't a Windows vs. Unix difference. Their main difference is in line endings. That file has every character in 2 bytes instead of 1. Is that UTF-16?

Comment: Looks like UTF-16LE, with a BOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your XML parser doesn't understand UTF-16.

You can convert it by opening an empty vim session and doing:

```
:e ++enc=utf-16le file.txt
:w ++enc=utf8
```

This will open the file with utf-16 little endian encoding, and the save it as utf-8.

Comment: D'oh. The real question is how I missed that it was UTF-16 ;-). Thanks for that, didn't know I could switch encoding types like that in Vim, appreciate the answer.